# PowerShell - Converting Date

Tags: powershell

How can I convert the Date 20131213113850.0Z to a date object?
Is there a build in command to convert for the get-date commandlet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where you do get such a timestamp? Knowing the origin makes it easier to parse it.

Comment: When you export a AD with "CSVDE -f data.csv" No access directly to the AD...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit on the interpretation of the digit to the right of the decimal but does this get you there:

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('20131213113850.0Z', 'yyyyMMddhhmmss.fK', $null)
```

The `K` specifier will convert the time to the local time zone.  Not sure if that is what you want or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But when I want to convert "2008012410102.0Z" it´s not working because 13:01:02 (German time Format) [DateTime]::ParseExact("2008012410102.0Z", 'yyyyMMddhhmmss.fK', $null) You know a solution?

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain this format a bit more.  For instance, do you need the hours to be 12 or 24 hour format?  I assume 0124 is Jan 24 but how do you interpret 10102 for hours/mins/secs? 1:01:02 or 10:10:02?

Comment: Sorry my fault! 20080124130102.0Z is valid!

Comment: I found it! yyyyMMddHHmmss.fK I need to use two uppercase HH because 24 h format!